# Accessing AppCtrl's variable in different controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Let's say this is my HTML:

```
<html ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
   <head>
      <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>
   <div ng-controller="MyController">
      Your name:
         {{$scope.AppCtrlsVariable}}
      <input type="text" ng-model="username">
      <button ng-click='sayHello()'>greet</button>
      <hr />
         {{greeting}}
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a variable named **AppCtrlsVariable** inside AppCtrl. How do I access it inside `div ng-controller="MyController"`. At the moment I get undefined when I try to access AppCtrl's variable inside MyController.

Could you please suggest what am I missing?

Comment: can you show me the controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the variable with `{{$scope.something}}` . It should be `{{something}}`

With nested controllers you can access the parent's variables. In case you overwrite it in inner controllers, you can also use `$scope.$parent.something`. [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/E5uqg/)

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
{{$scope.AppCtrlsVariable}} <!-- wrong -->
{{AppCtrlsVariable}} <!-- correct -->
<div ng-controller="MyController">
Your name: {{AppCtrlsVariable}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wasted 1 1/2 hr behind this issue.